Convert an existing product to a bundle and not a Kit
I have dived deeply in product catalog to solve my problem.
There are some existing products in my CRM365 CE that I would like to convert them to bundles. certainly these products have a unique productId.
These products now have some options(Product Association) which some of them are optional and the others are mandatory. Cause of this I can not use kits.( As you know all product associations in a kit are mandatory, and not optional)
There is button in ribbon of product record form named : convert to kit; but as I said these are some optional associated products.
Also I do not want to add new bundles with new productId, but convert existing products to bundles.
Is it possible?
